# Parallelize for loops in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Is there any possibility to parallelize the following code in python? I was wondering how to convert this code with map and lambda functions..

```
values = (1,2,3,4,5 )

def op(x,y):
    return x+y

[(i, j, op(i, j))
        for i in values
        for j in values
        if i is not j]
```

Comment: you may use the module  "multiprocessing" : see  https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Maybe by using map function?, Im newbie in python. because the iteration is taking a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parallelize the function op with multiprocessing and map:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from itertools import permutations

pool = ThreadPool(4)  # Number of threads

values = (1,2,3,4,5)
aux_val = [(i, j) for i,j in permutations(values,2)]

def op(tupx):
    result = (tupx[0], tupx[1], tupx[0] + tupx[1])
    return result

results = pool.map(op, aux_val)
```

Comment: well done! this is nearly what I had in mind! waiting to any other answer in order to get the simplest way.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
from itertools import permutations

values = (1,2,3,4,5 )
[(i, j, i+j) for i, j in permutations(values, 2)]
```

It's in python's stdlib.

If you want run in parallel, check out this using python3:

```
import multiprocessing
from itertools import permutations

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l = permutations(values, 2)


def f(x):
    return x[0], x[1], x[0] + x[1]

with multiprocessing.Pool(5) as p:
    data = p.map(f, l)
```

Comment: @PeCade I have add the parallel version using python3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **asyncio**. (Documentation can be found [here][1]). It is used as a foundation for multiple Python asynchronous frameworks that provide high-performance network and web-servers, database connection libraries, distributed task queues, etc. Plus it has both high-level and low-level APIs to accomodate any kind of problem.

```
import asyncio

def background(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

@background
def your_function(argument):
    #code
```

Now this function will be run in parallel whenever called without putting main program into wait state. You can use it to parallelize for loop as well. When called for a for loop, though loop is sequential but every iteration runs in parallel to the main program as soon as interpreter gets there.

For example for your specific case, you can do:

```
@background
def op(x,y):
    time.sleep(1) # Added sleep to demonstrate parallelization
    print(f"function called for {x=}, {y=}\n", end='')
    return x, y, x+y

values = [1,2,3,4,5]                                                     

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()           # Have a new event loop

looper = asyncio.gather(*[op(i, j)
        for i in values
        for j in values
        if i is not j])                   # Run the loop
                             
results = loop.run_until_complete(looper) # Wait until finish

print('Loop has finished and results are gathered!')      
results
```

This produces following output:

```
function called for x=1, y=5
function called for x=1, y=2
function called for x=2, y=3
function called for x=2, y=1
function called for x=1, y=3
function called for x=1, y=4
function called for x=2, y=4
function called for x=2, y=5
function called for x=3, y=1
function called for x=3, y=4
function called for x=4, y=1
function called for x=3, y=5
function called for x=3, y=2
function called for x=4, y=5
function called for x=4, y=3
function called for x=4, y=2
function called for x=5, y=3
function called for x=5, y=4
function called for x=5, y=2
function called for x=5, y=1
Loop has finished and results are gathered!
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 4), (1, 4, 5), (1, 5, 6), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6), (2, 5, 7), (3, 1, 4), (3, 2, 5), (3, 4, 7), (3, 5, 8), (4, 1, 5), (4, 2, 6), (4, 3, 7), (4, 5, 9), (5, 1, 6), (5, 2, 7), (5, 3, 8), (5, 4, 9)]
```