# How to parallelize the processing of multiple columns of a data in python?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pyspark, multiprocessing

I have a `DataFrame` as following:

```
col1  col2   col3    col4    col5    col5   col6                                            
 0.6  '0'   'first'  0.93   'lion'   0.34   0.98
 0.7  '1'  'second'  0.47    'cat'   0.43   0.76
 0.4  '0'   'third'  0.87  'tiger'   0.24   0.10
 0.6  '0'   'first'  0.93   'lion'   0.34   0.98
 0.5  '1'   'first'  0.32  'tiger'   0.09   0.99
 0.4  '0'   'third'  0.78  'tiger'   0.18   0.17
 0.5  '1'  'second'  0.98    'cat'   0.47   0.78
```

I need to take each column(say `col1` ,`col2` , `col3`, and so on..) from the above `DataFrame` in a for loop to a function as below:

```
list=[]
for col in df.columns:
    result = performDBSCAN(df[col])
    list.append([col,score])

def performDBSCAN(feature):
    ......(some implementation)
    score = scorecalculate(col)
    ......(some implementation
    return somevalue

def scorecalculate(feature):
    .......(some implementation)
    return scorecal
```

Basically, I wanted to run the above code for many columns which is taking more time to complete the processing time. I wanted to know how can I make it faster or to run parallel in python since I have 404 columns and 5000 rows. Also, I need some suggestions on whether I can do it in `Tensorflow` or `Spark`? (I ask this question since I had  no idea on `Spark` and `Tensorflow` but seeking for a suggestion)

Comment: does this answer help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50414300/efficient-column-processing-in-pyspark ?

Comment: No it doesn't help me. Basically, I need to perform dbscan algorithm on each column in a parallel fashion. The code which I wrote is taking large amounts of time(since it goes in serial execution manner). I also tried Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588931/parallelize-for-loops-in-python but could not help(It is executing but showing no output).